# From where the Magento getRowUrl function called in the grid

Tags: magento

Can anybody tell me that from where the Magento `getRowUrl()` function called in the grid view?

You can find this grid in any block..

```
app\code\community\Company\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Module\Grid.php
```

The function is defined there but do not know from where it is being called by Magento to return the row url

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is in the *widget/grid.phtml* template [(link)](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/widget/grid.phtml#L155):

```
<tbody>
<?php if (($this->getCollection()->getSize()>0) && (!$this->getIsCollapsed())): ?>
<?php foreach ($this->getCollection() as $_index=>$_item): ?>
    <tr title="<?php echo $this->getRowUrl($_item) ?>"<?php if ($_class = $this->getRowClass($_item)):?> class="<?php echo $_class; ?>"<?php endif;?> >
```